# Drupal Multilingual Page does not show 404 on not existing subpages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-multi-domain

I have a Webportal running with Drupal7, which is in multiple Languages. There's the Problem, that if I have the page "/test" and go on the browser to "/test/asdf" or /TeSt" I don't get a 404 - I get the page delivered as usual.

Does anyone know, why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for fixing this problem there is a module:

http://drupal.org/project/views404

http://drupal.org/node/1131834#comment-6461198